# Name parametrized Data type

Tags: haskell

I am learning (once again) haskell and I have the following code:

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map

data Union = Union
    {
        father :: Int,
        mother :: Int,
        offspring :: [Int]
    }
    deriving Show

data Person = Person
    {
        uid :: Int,
        name :: String,
        parentUnion :: Maybe Union,
        unions :: [Union]
    }
    deriving Show

family :: Map.Map Int Person
family = Map.fromList []

addPerson :: (Map.Map Int Person) -> Person -> (Map.Map Int Person)
addPerson family person
    | Map.member puid family = error "Repeated id"
    | otherwise = Map.insert puid person family
    where puid = uid person
```

Now with more functions, I will have quite a lot of `Map.Map Int Person` types. Is there a way to define a type `Family` which is the same as `Map.Map Int Person`, so I could spell:

```
addPerson :: Family -> Person -> Family
```

My naive approach:

```
data Family = Map.Map Int Person
```

gives me a nice error:

```
Qualified constructor in data type declaration
```

Comment: Tikhon Jelvis has addressed both [in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22445783/1598537). My first comment was made obselete by the first version of his answer and my second was made obselete by the current version. Accordingly I'm deleting them. This message will self-destruct in a non-deterministic time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. To create "type synonyms" like that, just use `type` instead of `data`:

```
type Family = Map.Map Int Person
```

This makes `Family` *exactly* the same as writing out `Map.Map Int Person`. In fact, error messages will sometimes write out the full version instead of the synonym, so be ready for that.

Another option is to use a `newtype`:

```
newtype Family = Family (Map.Map Int Person)
```

The difference is that the `newtype` version is, like the name says, a *new* type: it is not directly compatible with `Map.Map Int Person`. If you try to use one where the other is expected, you will get an error. This is probably less useful for your example, but can be used to encode additional invariants in your types.

The `newtype` version is almost identical to a `data` construction:

```
data Family = Family (Map.Map Int Person)
```

It also introduces a new constructor `Family` which takes a single argument. However, unlike a normal data type, this only exists at *compile time*; the runtime representations of `Family` and `Map.Map Int Person` would still be exactly the same.